# How to create a recently viewed articles grid in umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I want to create a grid which shows top two recently visited pages of a website when the user has logged in. The website is on umbraco.

Comment: make a db of recently visited pages and retriev the data from DB or use cookies..

Comment: I cannot touch the DB so I guess Cookies would help. Could you please elaborate on how to use cookies to do this work?

Comment: Hi Kirthika, when you say "user" are you referring to a visitor of your site, or an Umbraco user logging into the back office? Aside from that, you would need to implement a mechanism to track page views or interact with your Google Analytics to try and retrieve the last viewed pages.

Comment: Hi, User as in the members who would use the site to sign in and browse through the resources and not the one who would log in to the back end of the website. Does Google analytics give details of the pages visited by each and every person who logs into the website?